# List of MD5 Hashes for Random Data Does Not Appear Uniform (PHP)

Tags: php, hash, md5

If I hash a bunch of random numbers in PHP and convert the hashes to base-10, it turns out that the digit 9 never appears toward the end of the resultant integers. I think I must be missing something obvious in the way MD5 hashing works or the way PHP handles it.

I noticed this because I have a list of (all different) strings and need to randomly bucket them into two groups (with 90% of the strings in bucket A and 10% in the bucket B). I figured I could just hash the strings, convert to base-10, and do something like this:

if( ( md5_hash_in_base_ten % 100 ) < 90 ) use bucket A

else use bucket B

But it turns out that the 9 digit was never appearing near the end of the resultant integers, so bucket B was never chosen.

I know there could be a million ways to randomly group strings, but I'm not interested in different solutions to that problem. I'm just curious about the (possible) odd results of my test code.

```php
for( $i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++ ) {
    $r = rand();
    $bc = base_convert( md5( $r ), 16, 10 );
    echo $bc . '<br>';
}
```

One chunk of results looks like this:

302600829905161600608260662606624826442
59585669553455458666446844468880068068
330999075520965568846868468088242088640
192131673950084244086840262480428482262
219128507900677482440460800240644480082
255318670176792246888206600668682602264
240208061481025440684246208684488420642
294217394926758646048046684044640488204
278449747058183168002848628868886688226
195713211929924564840668644204640202264
249037264096573760228220842660668480862
207646493898559360028468248404088664884
169051134173421386202080006468046600882
91273057168422960202446286266888840680
289959365012917366428044866648660802042
172462762250895562808826226442626868482
21264346015514864044284484068442686886
37414331404805136842220266424646680664
76064003552382186484240646428006806660
316804269790551588866666266482482808288
142781990240421424242486286048486626288
12211092583070068208404402226428806286
164064659807615146666228064640060626026
336702095492281784288600868224440806802
264447819530445920480408448628866828002
127283138187204864060642440804622660688
220658311731241408862084402042406680248
71873545317929552826606228242842664868

And if we ctrl-F that for the number 9, it looks like this:

[image: md5 9 distribution]

Ideas?

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to use the entropy in the strings to divide them up 90/10.  If you need perfect balance you will need to keep it that way manually, otherwise using the first letter of the string instead of the MD5 would be just as useful without all the overhead.  Maybe use an id, primary key or something similar?

Comment: It's fallacious to use `convert_base` on `md5`'s output because `md5`'s output **does not represent a number**: its output represents a vector of octets (i..e `byte[]`). Instead, break `md5`'s string output into groups of 2 characters (thus representing each octet) and then use `convert_base`.

Comment: @Dai I disagree. You are right that `md5`'s output is intended to be interpreted as a byte array rather than a number, but as a cryptographic hash function it should generate 128 bits, where each should be 0 or 1 with almost the same probability. So nothing stops you from interpreting this as a number and doing further computations on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's `base_convert` function is **not made for arbitrarily large numbers**, as the [red box on the function's documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) indicates.

You can verify that yourself the following way:

```php
echo ('a' == base_convert(base_convert('a', 16, 10), 10, 16)) ? 1 : 0;
echo ('abcdefabcdefabcdef' == base_convert(base_convert('abcdefabcdefabcdef', 16, 10), 10, 16)) ? 1 : 0;
```

This will print `1` and `0`: Converting the number `a` (hex) to decimal and back works as expected, but the number `abcdefabcdefabcdef` (hex) causes `base_convert` to loose precision.

To work around this problem, you need to use a function that is able to handle numbers of arbitrary length. For an example, check out [one of the comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#106546) on the documentation page (function `convBase`).

Comment: I figured it had to be something obvious... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're using a bigger number than base_convert can handle. Refer to the PHP documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php).

And MD5 hash is 128 bits, which is more than most libraries are expected to handle. Your converted result can't hold the precision. In your case you can use the [GNU Multiple Precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) library.

```
<?php

/*use gmp library to convert base. gmp will convert numbers > 32bit*/
function gmp_convert($num, $base_a, $base_b)
{
        return gmp_strval ( gmp_init($num, $base_a), $base_b );
}

for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    $r = rand();
    $h = md5($r);
    $bc = base_convert( $h, 16, 10 );
    $gmp = gmp_convert( $h, 16, 10 );
    echo "Random value:   " . $r . PHP_EOL;
    echo "MD5 Hash:       " . $h . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Base converted: " . $bc . PHP_EOL;
    echo "GMP converted:  " . $gmp . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Which will ouput:

```
$ php -f foo.php
Random value:   1198279904
MD5 Hash:       714ae450dedfd56314b47f84e1922c9a
Base converted: 150591624287845962826662264228684068862
GMP converted:  150591624287845974934538261676650802330
Random value:   2000471768
MD5 Hash:       6359b22761538dd02822732ba45c66bf
Base converted: 132059299392045104262828066404880468000
GMP converted:  132059299392045115619248080281367504575
Random value:   851022648
MD5 Hash:       1e95df1b73599a92637982bab7814fc4
Base converted: 40655017257670256242606204044284220868
GMP converted:  40655017257670268183638196631434776516
Random value:   711523039
MD5 Hash:       e23aff29be3bb611abbb3736fbdd4d07
Base converted: 300711855586863926204240426446264628688
GMP converted:  300711855586863939825593015112763788551
Random value:   953421999
MD5 Hash:       a5990cd2bbab7707db05ebd3b468df17
Base converted: 220117300808777322406606064084840664268
GMP converted:  220117300808777304730115892103715806999
```